# Bulk resave entries to trigger onSaveEntry event

Tags: events, updates, onsaveentry

I have a site with a hundred+ or so entries. I've added a new field to my entry template, but it won't take effect until it's been activated by a [onSaveEntry](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#listening-for-events) event.

I've gone through maybe 15 entries or so now and resaved them manually, but it's proving to be a long and painstaking process.

Is there a way for me to batch resave all enabled entries in order to trigger this `onSaveEntry` event?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you re-save the section(s) that your entries are in, it should re-trigger a save of all of the entries.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is the correct answer, I don't see why it was down voted. Go to "Settings > Sections" and then the section containing your entries and hit save. This will trigger a bulk re-save of all of the entries.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - got my upvote.

Comment: This did in fact resave all entries (there was a task that ran in my sidebar confirming as much: https://cl.ly/221m2V0p2i41). Didn't seem to trigger the onSaveEntry event though; my field's values have gone unchanged. Is this intentional or am I missing something?

Comment: I have this exact problem with 2000+ entries, how did you eventually manage to do this? Re saving the section doesn't work

Comment: This is a good solution, except it does not seem to resave the localized versions of each entry. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Two-year-ago Jake, you beauty. Thanks! Works great in Craft 3.

Comment: on craft 3.2.10 saving the section has no effect on the search-index only the "craft resave/entries" command worked for me but there is no documentation for that

Answer (score 5):

Craft can now do this via the CLI

https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#resave-entries

Comment: Does this trigger events like `Entry::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE`? I can get the command line `resave/entries` to work but Events don't seem to be firing.