# Bulk resave user entries to trigger onSaveEntry event

Tags: users, onsaveentry

Is it possible to bulk save user entries to force an onSaveEntry event. I added a new custom preparse field to Users, but need to trigger a save event to propagate.

Regular sections can reindex by saving the Section title ([Bulk resave entries to trigger onSaveEntry event](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18448/bulk-resave-entries-to-trigger-onsaveentry-event/18449#18449)) but it doesn't seem like that's possible with Users? Any known workarounds or obvious tricks I'm missing?

Comment: Would it be an option to create the function by yourself or does it have to be during the `onSaveEntry` event every time?

Comment: Good question -- not sure, frankly